# Perl script slower on other server compared to dev (with same spec)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, perl, mysql5.7

I'm trying to figure out why a **Perl** script I have, isn't performing anywhere near as well once I put it on the live server.

The whole script is identical on both servers (one is a test server, the other the live one). Both are running this version of Perl:

```
This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
(with 73 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

The dev server is running:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Whereas the live server is on a slightly different version:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

my.cnf files are the same on both servers. Could having such a smaller difference in mySQL versions cause the speed issues? Both servers are 8GB RAM,

The script has a lot of work to do (building static pages for a directory), and takes this long on each server:

- Dev server: 40 minutes
- Live server: 2 hours 20 minutes

As you can see, that's a whopping difference. Any suggestions on what else I could try?

Here is how `htop` looks on the live server when running the script:

[image]

and then on the dev server:

[image]

Doesn't seem to be much in it (or any swap being used)

Comment: Different data size in DB?

Comment: @CloudAce thanks. Its the exact same data, same table structure, same indexes. Really baffling me. The only difference is the dev server has a 2048mb swap, whereas live has 512mb swap - but from what I've read, that's not really even relevant with an 8Gb ram server?

Comment: Well, since this is the only difference, its worth to have a look, just to make sure.

Comment: @CloudAce  just done it, and starting a build now. Will see how long it takes (and if it made a difference)

Comment: @CloudAce unfortunately it didn't help :(  I've added the output of  `htop` on both the live and dev server. If anything, the dev server has more stuff running on it (so you would expect it to be slower).

Comment: Then maybe you should profile the script to see where cost time most

Comment: @CloudAce any suggestions on the best way to do that? Is there a server tool that can do it, or would I need to do it in the Perl script?

Comment: For example, `Devel::NYTProf`, or you can just use plain print in your script to measure the execution time

Comment: @CloudAce thanks - will have a play and come back with my finding s:)